# Por que colocar arquivo .jsp no diretório WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsp

Tomando o Maven como exemplo, quando iniciado um novo projeto web, a estrutura é igual/semelhante a esta:

```
Meu Projeto
    |- src
        |- main
            |- java
            |- resources
            |- webapp
                 |- WEB-INF
```

Onde, no diretório "webapp" são colocados os arquivos utilizados pela aplicação web: html, css, Javascript, JSPs, etc.

A minha dúvida é em relação ao diretório WEB-INF, existem vários projetos que utilizam esse diretório para colocar os arquivos com extensão .jsp, ao invés de colocá-los diretamente em "webapp". Um exemplo é o [Mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) da Caelum, onde eles criaram um diretório chamado "jsps" para isto.

Pelo que li a respeito, os arquivos contidos em WEB-INF não podem ser acessados diretamente pelo cliente pois não são públicos, mas podem ser acessados pelos servlets:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the container**. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` method calls on the `ServletContext`, **and may be exposed using the `RequestDispatcher` calls**.

Então seria somente por segurança? A única forma de obter os arquivos seria ao ser processado por meio de um servlet.

Answer (score 2):

9.10 Escondendo nossas páginas - https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/mvc-model-view-controller/

Se as páginas ficarem em /webapp, o usuário terá acesso direto a elas. Se forem somente páginas estáticas, não vejo problema. Mas algumas páginas precisam de uma lógica antes de serem exibidas, caso o usuário acesse o jsp diretamente a página não será exibida corretamente, não irá passar pelo controller.

"Portanto, não devemos permitir que o usuário acesse diretamente nossa página. Para impossibilitar este acesso direto, colocaremos nossas páginas dentro do diretório WEB-INF/"